# Converting Array of arrays to LatLang as Polygon paths

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I need to convert array of arrays to `LatLang` and use as a path parameter in a polygon. My array looks like this:

```
 let jsonArrays = [
     [
       "-112.3240289",
       "33.5096918"
     ],
     [
       "-112.3240288",
       "33.5096836"
      ],
     [
        "-112.3240144",
        "33.507364"
      ],
      ...and thousands more


  for (let i = 0; i < jsonArrays.length; i++) {
        let gData = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(jsonArrays[i][0]), parseFloat(jsonArrays[i][1]));
        latLngArray.push(gData);
    }
    let poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: latLngArray,
        strokeColor: '#00a153',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 3,
        // fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0
    })
```

But this doesn't work. I got no error and polygons does not appear. [This is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zirCm.png) what I get when I inspect the `latLngArray` contents.

So, exactly I need a polygon like [this one](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?place_id=239657711), and the data I'm taking is from [here](https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=Phoenix&state=AZ&format=json&polygon=1&addressdetails=1).

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latitude must be between 90 and -90 degrees.  In your array, the first number is outside the range for valid latitudes (`["-112.3240289","33.5096918"]`), so must be longitude (also, FYI, the GeoJSON spec defines geographic coordinates that way `[longitude, latitude]`).

Change your code to use the coordinates in the right order:

```
let gData = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(jsonArrays[i][1]), parseFloat(jsonArrays[i][0]));
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/uL80g3e4/2) (with a couple of added points).

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: {
      lat: 24.886,
      lng: -70.268
    },
    mapTypeId: 'terrain'
  });
  var latLngArray = [];
  let jsonArrays = [
    ["-112.3240289", "33.5096918"],
    ["-112.3240288", "33.5096836"],
    ["-112.3240144", "33.507364"],
    ["-112.327685", "33.5073"],
    ["-112.327728", "33.51"],
    ["-112.324016", "33.51"],
  ]


  for (let i = 0; i < jsonArrays.length; i++) {
    let gData = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(jsonArrays[i][1]), parseFloat(jsonArrays[i][0]));
    latLngArray.push(gData);
  }
  let poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: latLngArray,
    strokeColor: '#00a153',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 3,
    // fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0,
    map: map
  });
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < poly.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
    bounds.extend(poly.getPath().getAt(i));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the value of `paths` needs to be an [array of objects](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple), you can try it in this another way:

```
let jsonArrays = [
  ['-112.3240289', '33.5096918'],
  ['-112.3240288', '33.5096836'],
  ['-112.3240144', '33.507364'],
  ['-112.3240289', '33.5096918']
];

const newCoords = jsonArrays.map(val => ({
  lat: parseFloat(val[1]), // y value
  lng: parseFloat(val[0])  // x value
}));

let poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
  paths: newCoords,
  strokeColor: '#00a153',
  strokeOpacity: 0.8,
  strokeWeight: 3,
  // fillColor: '#FF0000',
  fillOpacity: 0
});
```

With [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) you can return your original array converted into a new array of objects, which includes your `lat` and `lng`, but **swapped.**